# Excel 2013 app, jQuery, WCF call fails with "no transport" error

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf, excel, office-2013

The programming environment is:
- Windows 8 desktop;
- WCF service;
- Excel 2013 office app;
- Both WCF service and Excel office app running on the same machine;
- The office app makes an ajax call to the WCF service;
The javascript code (used in the office app) where the problem occurs is:

```
function F() {
  $.support.cors = true;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "http://localhost:5000/<service>/<method>",
    data: '{<my data>}',
    dataType: "json",
    success: ...
    error: ...
   });
}
```

Here is the problem I have - when I call a WCF service from Excel 2013 app I get a "no transport" error. I was able to identify teh following use cases:
1) This happens only when I run a standalone Excel 2013 instance and insert the app from the "Insert" Excel menu.
2) If I run the app from VS2012, then everything is fine, I can call the WCF service without any problems. (BTW, the WCF service is run on the same machine. The request I am making from the Excel 2013 app is an ajax one.).
3) The same case as (2). The app can make WCF calls. Then I also insert an instance of my app from the Excel "Insert" menu. In this case if I try to make a WCF call with the inserted app instance I get the same error as in (1) - "no transport".

I did some search on the Internet and found that my problem might be related to the fact the call I am trying to make is a cross-domain call. (BTW, I debugged the jQuery code and the call is really a cross-domain one). The suggested solution was to set one of the jQuery properties before the call: "jQuery.support.cors = true;". I did that in my Excel 2013 app code, but the problem was not solved. Then I traced the calls in jQuery code and found that:

1) When the app is run from VS2012, jQuery creates two transport objects: (1) one for cross-domain requests and (2) one where the cross-domain requests are allowed only through XMLHttpRequest.
When a WCF call is made from the app, jQuery uses the second transport and the call is successful.

2) When the app is inserted from the Excel 2013 "Insert" menu, then before the WCF call jQuery creates only one transport object, for cross-domain requests. Then jQuery "decides" it is not possible to use that transport object and the request fails with "no transport" errror.

Any idea why this happens amd how the problem can be solved?